# Javauto Compile fails (Getting started)

Tags: java, compiler-errors

Following [Getting started](http://javauto-lang.org/docs/getting-started.html) - 
(Windows 7, console: C:...>, .jar & .javauto in the same folder)

```
java -jar javauto.jar              => OK, help is displayed 
javauto hello.javauto              => command not recognised                   
javauto.jar hello.javauto          => NO result
```

So i tried this

```
java -jar javauto.jar -v hello.javauto
```

Giving this exception (NB: c:...>javac  => help display is OK)

```
Generating ←[92mhello←[0m...
Getting user imports...  None
Getting user global variables...  None
Getting user functions...  None
Generating functions...  ←[93mmouseMove ←[0m←[93mmsgBox ←[0m←[93mprint ←[0m←[93msleep ←[0m
Generating class variables...  ←[93msimulatedMotionSpeed ←[0m
Generating imports...  ←[93mAWTException ←[0m←[93mMouseInfo ←[0m←[93mRobot ←[0m←[93mJDialog ←[0m←[93
mJOptionPane ←[0m
Generating struct objects... None
Generation complete... starting build
Executing cmd /c attrib +s +h  "C:\Users\Francis\Develop\java\Javauto\.hello"...
Building  ←[92mC:\Users\Francis\Develop\java\Javauto\.hello\class\hello.class←[0m...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Couldn't find java system compiler.
    at com.automation.javauto.compiler.CustomJavaCompiler.compile(CustomJavaCompiler.java:36)
    at com.automation.javauto.parser.Create.main(Create.java:419)
```

Comment: Do you have JAVA_HOME set, as well as the jdk on your PATH?

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that perhaps your javac is someplace really weird, and javauto is mis-parsing the path when trying to execute?

Comment: Environment is OK (javac compiles outside javauto) : 
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_74  - - - 
Path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_74\bin

Comment: The interesting part is probably in the "Exception" line (outside my reach...).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**1)** Compile it using this command:

```
java -jar javauto.jar  hello.javauto
```

**2)** Now that you have compiled your program, there will be a file called **hello.jar**. Execute with:

```
java -jar hello.jar
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what i did ... resulting in the exception described above.

Comment: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException" ==> some help : http://howtodoinjava.com/core-java/exception-handling/how-to-effectively-handle-nullpointerexception-in-java/